# Table with border image

Tags: html, css, html-table

Give this code to make a border Image around cells. Is it possible to make the border between the cells only show one border? And also that the red squares are only at the Corners of the table and not at every Corner of the cell. (like a normal table would be displayed but the lines get replaced with an Images of squares)

If a solution exits for this that uses an external libary or jquery, just let me know.

```css
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th, .table-bordered > thead > tr > td, .table-bordered > thead > tr > th {
    border: 0; /* reset */
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px;
    -moz-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
    -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
    border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 fill round;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Bar</th>
            <th>Lols</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                something here
            </td>
            
            <td>
                whatever
            </td>
            
            <td>
                6,0% / 12% wag.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @mplungjan the first part of the question is duplicate but he `And also that the red squares are only at the Corners of the table and not at every Corner of the cell` So I think this not entirely duplicated from that

Comment: If the answer to the second question is not found in the link I gave, you can ask another question as you should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking something like this.

```css
td,
th {
  border: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  -moz-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
  -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
  border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 fill round;
  border-width: 0 0 25px;
}


.table {
  border: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px;
  -moz-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
  -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 round;
  border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 27 fill round;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Foo</th>
      <th>Bar</th>
      <th>Lols</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        something here
      </td>

      <td>
        whatever
      </td>

      <td># 6,0% / 12% wag.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I didnt even think about giving the table a border +1. I will combine this with the "border only on one side" solution from the linked question so I get the vertical bars too.